# Can't read thumbnails on Android 10 (loadThumbnail)

Tags: android, mediastore

I'm reading thumbnails from the device by querying the MediaStore, using `MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail()`. However, this has been deprecated in Android 10 (API 29), with a pointer to `ContentResolver#loadThumbnail`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails

However, I can't get this to work (in an emulated device running API 29). I've copied some JPEGs onto the emulated device, which end up in the Downloads folder. They show up fine in the Photos app. The following code gives me a FileNotFoundException. What does "No content provider" actually tell me?

```
try {

    Size thumbSize = new Size(100, 100);
    Uri thumbUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(imgPath));
    // imgPath: /storage/emulated/0/Download/pexels-photo-323490.jpeg
    // thumbUri: file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/pexels-photo-323490.jpeg

    Bitmap thumbBitmap;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        thumbBitmap = mContext.getContentResolver().loadThumbnail(thumbUri, thumbSize, null);
    } else {
        thumbBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(mContext.getContentResolver(),
                imgId, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, null);
    }

    iconView.setImageBitmap(thumbBitmap);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("err", e.toString());
}
```

Exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/pexels-photo-323490.jpeg
```

Comment: have you created a content provider? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html

Comment: Yes, I have a ContentProvider which interfaces the MediaStore: `public class PhotoProvider extends ContentProvider`. My query method returns a cursor which contains, among other fields, the thumbnail "data" (i.e. path): `String thumbData = cursor.getString(PhotoFragment.COL_THUMB_DATA);`

Comment: The pasted code is from my `RecyclerViewCursorAdapter` class, which binds a row from the cursor to a view element in a RecyclerView (grid).

Comment: ... so I was thinking that my Content Provider sort of had done its job at this point. It has retrieved the data from the MediaStore -- including the path -- and the adapter class should just display it in the UI. But I understand that bitmaps do require a certain amount of extra work :)

Comment: Is it really asking for *my* content provider?

Comment: `file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/pexels-photo-323490.jpeg` If you use an uri like that then no content provider is involved. And not yours either. Function .loadThumbnail() will never work with such an uri.

Comment: Thanks for replying! But you see the scenario here: I'm getting all images from the MediaStore. What, then, is the proper way to load the thumbnails as bitmaps into the UI? The uri, by the way, is what I get from the recommended `fromFile` method...

Comment: Getting all the _metadata_, that is.

Comment: Could you perhaps clarify how to get a usable uri from querying the MediaStore?

Comment: Please try this, hope it works for You `int thumbColumn = cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID);
int _thumpId = cur.getInt(thumbColumn);
                
Uri imageUri_t = imageUri_t = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,_thumpId);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try this, hope it works for You:

```
int thumbColumn = cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID); 
int _thumpId = cur.getInt(thumbColumn); 
Uri imageUri_t = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,_thumpId);
```

GGK

Comment: Thanks, @GGK! I now get a usable uri, of type content://media/external/images/media/31

Comment: How come I failed to use this Uri for the `loadThumbnail` function for getting album art of mp3 files using the query Uri of `MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL)` ? It keeps getting me `FileNotFoundException` (and I have the storage permission granted)... Can you please post full sample code for this? Or maybe this is all intended only for image files?

Comment: Thats while album arts are embedded in mp3 audio files. You have to use `uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL);` instead of and fetch the album art using `MediaMetadataRetriever`

Answer (score 2):

The best Answer for getting Thumbnail and All Android Versions is this:

```
val thumbnail: Bitmap = if ((Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)) {
    mContentResolver.loadThumbnail(contentUri, Size(width / 2, height / 2), null)
} else {
    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(mContentResolver, id, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, null)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The uri may not be good. I mean try using FileProvider to get uri of the file. If your legecyExternalStorage is false, then you can not access file like this. The same goes for android 12. You need to use MediaStore to get the contentUri